# Quiero poner muchos links en una web?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que hacer una web en la cual voy a poner **muchos** enlaces,es decir, un enlace  detrás de otro.Lo mas lógico es poner en el html con la etiqueta `<a>` pero me preguntaba si habla alguna manera mas rápida de poner muchos, ya sea en JavaScript o en php...

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren. Muéstranos que has intentado?

Comment: Con un for puedes poner todos los que quieras.

Comment: SI, gracias por responder pero lo que pasa es que no va a ser el mimo href en cada enlace , y igual pongo 500 enlaces y cambiar todos los href va a ser una tarea tediosa.. Entiedes lo que quiero decir ? Aveces no me explico muy bien...

Comment: Y los enlaces los ingresas tú de alguna forma o simplemente lo pones tú directamente en el código con lo que tu quieras?

Comment: SI, mira lo que pasa es que tengo que hacer un pequeño proyecto para clase. Y quiero hacer una web en la cual aparezcan todo tipo de links los cuales los pondré en categorías(ej: categoría de Juegos : paisdelosjuegos.com, juegosjuegos.com ...etc). Y entonces solo preguntaba si hay alguna forma  mas cómoda de poner muchos links. Espero que se haya entendido un poco mejor.

Comment: Pues podrías tener una base de datos dónde los guardes y los categorices, de acuerdo a eso puedes hacer ciertas consultas y para mostrarlos recorres el arreglo en dónde guardas las consultas algo así, no es muy complicado, es la forma más simple en la que lo veo

Comment: Uff , un poco complicado para mi que estoy empezando con las bases de datos.Bueno muchas gracias igualmente,creo que tendré que cojér el pico y la pala. Investigare sobre lo que me has dicho  @DaxTter77 y lo intentaré.

Comment: Pues sí te toca investigar, es complicado cuando lo haces todo directamente del código ya que tienes que modificar tú mismo cada enlace y sí van a ser muchos, no es una buena practica, en cambio en una base de datos los guardas todos, haces la respectiva consulta y para plasmarlo en el html es simplemente recorrer el arreglo, te deseo suerte con tu proyecto, igual sí tienes dudas puedes plantear una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Puedes hacer un objeto en Javascript y ciclarlo. No importa si es una base de datos, un objeto o todo en HTML, tendrás que colocar TU los enlaces. A menos que quieras hacer un web crawler, pero esos ya son temas muy avanzados si vas empezando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te lo comenté la forma más factible en la que veo que puedes hacer eso que quieres es guardando en una base de datos los enlaces que quieres tener en tu pagina, cómo para que te puedas ir guiando la tabla puede ser `enlaces` con los campos `id_enlace`, `enlace`, `categoria` en esta tabla ingresas todos los enlaces que vayas a poner y cómo dices que los vas a clasificar en la categoría lo pones, pero también en categoria para que no tenga que estar ingresando tú manualmente, puedes hacer un enlace con otra tabla para que no haya redundancia de datos, ejemplo: tenemos en la tabla `categoria` con los campos `id_cat`, `categoria`, entonces aquí pones las categorías que vayas a tener y enlazas con una llave foranea esta tabla con la tabla `enlaces` entonces simplemente señalas el datos, entonces sí "videojuegos" es de id **1** entonces en la tabla enlaces en el campo categoría colocas **1**.

Teniendo las tablas ya simplemente con `PHP` haces una conexión con mysqli a la base de datos y ya harías una consulta en la base de datos para los que quieres traer, entonces sí quieres hacer una consulta solamente de los enlaces de videojuegos, la haces y recorres el arreglo que queda, te dejaré enlaces de guía para que puedas estudiar.

[Crear una base de datos mysql phpmyadmin](https://disenowebakus.net/crear-una-base-de-datos-phpmyadmin-mysql-php.php)

[Llaves primarías y foráneas](https://ingsystemas.webnode.es/bases-de-datos/llaves-primarias-y-foraneas/)

[Conectar una base de datos mysql desde php](http://www.oscarabadfolgueira.com/conectar-una-base-datos-mysql-desde-php/)

Espero que te sirva, saludos!! sí tienes dudas no dudes en plantearla.

Comment: Valee, muchas gracias @DaxTter77 ya me estoy mirando lo que me has pasado. Lo bueno es que tengo unos 2 meses, y lo iré haciendo con la calma.Seguramente tendré muchas dudas con lo de las bases de datos. Pero poco a poco...

Comment: Sí, dale, igual también sí lo deseas me avisas y creamos una sala de chat para irte ayudando, no es muy difícil, pero como apenas empiezas se te complica un poco, de igual manera esta comunidad es grande y cualquiera te puede ayudar con problemas concretos, suerte con el proyecto